# how to keep just the upper element from a series same elements and remove the others

Tags: matlab

The following matrix:

```
A = [ -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 0 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0 -1 1 -1 1 0 0 ]
```

Would be like this:

```
A = [ -1 1           0 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0 -1 1      0 0 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting little problem. I believe this works:

```
A = [-1 1 -1 1 -1 1 0 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0 -1 1 -1 1 0 0]; %# Set up an example vector
I1 = [1, 1, A(1:end-2) - A(3:end)]; %# Index all repetitions of sets of two using zeros
I1(A == 0) = 1; %# Ensure our index doesn't remove any of the 0's from the original vector
Soln = A(I1 ~= 0); %# Obtain solution using nonzero entries of the index
```

Comment: @joeblack No probs. If you're happy with my answer, feel free to click the tick mark next to it so the question is marked answered. If not, let me know why and perhaps I can improve it. Cheers.